# Playing movie in beamer using multimedia

Tags: beamer, viewers, animate, media9, multimedia

I try to include movies in my presentations.
I tried the **multimedia** package and the **media9** package.
I also tried Acrobat Reader, Foxit Reader, PDF xChange and pympress as PDF reader.

The only working solution is media9 package with Acrobat Reader and maybe Foxit (haven't installed Flash Player) or external player of course.

Multimedia support is activated in all players.

I also tried .avi and .mp4 files (h264 codec)

Overview:

- multimedia package & mp4 & Acrobat Reader:
  video is clickable but it only appears a gray frame, nothing else
- multimedia package & mp4 & Foxit Reader:
  just nothing
- multimedia package & mp4 & pdf xChange:
  just nothing
- multimedia package & mp4 & pympress:
  video starts playing but with video defect and video noise
- media9 package & mp4 & Acrobat Reader:
  working
- media9 package & mp4 & Foxit Reader:
  Install Flash Player (don't like to)
- media9 package & mp4 & PDF xChange Reader:
  nothing
- media9 package & mp4 & PDF pympress:
  nothing
- multimedia package & avi & Acrobat Reader:
  video is clickable but it only appears a gray frame, nothing else
- multimedia package & avi & Foxit Reader:
  just nothing
- multimedia package & avi & pdf xChange:
  just nothing
- multimedia package & avi & pympress:
  video starts playing but with video defect and video noise
- media9 package & avi & Acrobat Reader:
  loading movie but not starting to play
- media9 package & avi & Foxit Reader:
  Install Flash Player (don't like to)
- media9 package & avi & PDF xChange Reader:
  Install Flash Player (don't like to)
- media9 package & avi & PDF pympress:
  video starts playing but with video defect and video

I would like to solve it with the multimedia package because I don't like including the movie file into the pdf (big pdf files) and I don't like Acrobat Reader.

Any suggestions? Any help please. Thx

```
\documentclass[bookmarks=true]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{media9,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includemedia[
  addresource=pendel.avi,
  flashvars={
     source=pendel.avi
    &autoPlay=true
  }]{playMovie}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
            \movie[%
                height = 54mm,%
                width = 96mm,%
                showcontrols,%
                ,once
            ]%
            {playMovie}
            {pendel.avi}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution was using Okular as pdf Viewer and mutlimedia package.